# How to ask a user to enter a welcome message? Then, how to do I print this custom message to other users?

Tags: bash, printing, users, input, multiple-users

I should execute necessary bash commands to print this custom message automatically to other users.

Comment: Is this a homework question? have you investigated the `wall` command?

Comment: yes I tried wall,   echo "enter a text"

read varname

wall "welcome $varname" but it does not display it for other users

Comment: I tried to take the user input then redirected to mesg y but it is not working